# why loadrunner loadrunner web_reg_save_param_ex don't work

Tags: loadrunner

I use loadrunner loading test ,want to get parameter with web_reg_save_param_ex function. but replay don't get value which I want , replay log as follows , the "DEV_PLATFORM\r\n" is I want to get .

```
Starting iteration 1.
Starting action Action.
Action.c(3): web_set_max_html_param_len started     [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(3): web_set_max_html_param_len was successful      [MsgId: MMSG-26392]
Action.c(5): web_reg_save_param_ex started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(5): Registering web_reg_save_param_ex was successful   [MsgId: MMSG-26390]
Action.c(14): web_add_cookie started    [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(14): web_add_cookie was successful     [MsgId: MMSG-26392]
Action.c(16): web_url("rdms") started   [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(16): t=59673ms: Connecting [0] to host server:8080     [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(16): t=59684ms: Connected socket [0] from 192.168.1.89:1288 to server:8080 in 2 ms     [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(16): t=59691ms: 364-byte request headers for "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(16):     GET /rdms HTTP/1.1\r\n
Action.c(16):     User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; 
Action.c(16):     .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)\r\n
Action.c(16):     Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Action.c(16):     Accept-Language: zh-cn\r\n
Action.c(16):     Accept: */*\r\n
Action.c(16):     Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Action.c(16):     Host: server:8080\r\n
Action.c(16):     Cookie: com.mansuo.base.product.ProductCode=Portal\r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16): t=59802ms: 168-byte response headers for "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(16):     HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n
Action.c(16):     Location: http://www.mansuo.com/rdms/\r\n
Action.c(16):     Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
Action.c(16):     Date: Sun, 30 Jun 2013 05:13:08 GMT\r\n
Action.c(16):     Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16): t=59951ms: 5-byte chunked response overhead for "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(16):     0\r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16): Redirecting "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms" (redirection depth is 0)     [MsgId: MMSG-26694]
Action.c(16): To location "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms/"     [MsgId: MMSG-26693]
Action.c(16): t=59993ms: Request done "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms"      [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(16): t=60021ms: Connecting [1] to host server:8080     [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(16): t=60029ms: Connected socket [1] from 192.168.1.89:1289 to server:8080 in 1 ms     [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(16): t=60037ms: 365-byte request headers for "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms/" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=2)
Action.c(16):     GET /rdms/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
Action.c(16):     User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; 
Action.c(16):     .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)\r\n
Action.c(16):     Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Action.c(16):     Accept-Language: zh-cn\r\n
Action.c(16):     Accept: */*\r\n
Action.c(16):     Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Action.c(16):     Host: server:8080\r\n
Action.c(16):     Cookie: com.mansuo.base.product.ProductCode=Portal\r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16): t=60134ms: 295-byte response headers for "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms/" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=2)
Action.c(16):     HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Action.c(16):     Pragma: No-cache\r\n
Action.c(16):     Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
Action.c(16):     Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT\r\n
Action.c(16):     Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E43A3FDEF770917EB3AFC7FB548A914A; Path=/rdms\r\n
Action.c(16):     Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n
Action.c(16):     Content-Length: 310\r\n
Action.c(16):     Date: Sun, 30 Jun 2013 05:13:08 GMT\r\n
Action.c(16):     Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16): Conversion from "utf-8" (code page 65001, preferred charset=utf-8, Unicode converter name="utf-8") will be performed for response of URL="http://www.mansuo.com/rdms/"    [MsgId: MMSG-35184]
Action.c(16): t=60251ms: 301-byte response body for "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms/" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=2)
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16):     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">\r\n
Action.c(16):     <html>\r\n
Action.c(16):     <head>\r\n
Action.c(16):     <title>DEV_PLATFORM</title>\r\n
Action.c(16):     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />\r\n
Action.c(16):     </head>\r\n
Action.c(16):     \r\n
Action.c(16):     <body>\r\n
Action.c(16):     <script language="JavaScript">\r\n
Action.c(16):     location="login.jsp";\r\n
Action.c(16):     </script>\r\n
Action.c(16):     </body>\r\n
Action.c(16):     </html>\r\n
Action.c(16): t=60525ms: Request done "http://www.mansuo.com/rdms/"     [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(16): Error -26377: No match found for the requested parameter "newParam". Check whether the requested boundaries exist in the response data. Also, if the data you want to save exceeds 1000000 bytes, use web_set_max_html_param_len to increase the parameter size   [MsgId: MERR-26377]
Action.c(16): Notify: Saving Parameter "newParam_count = 0".
Action.c(16): web_url("rdms") highest severity level was "ERROR", 310 body bytes, 463 header bytes, 5 chunking overhead bytes   [MsgId: MMSG-26387]
Ending action Action.
Ending iteration 1.
```

my script as follows ,why  web_reg_save_param_ex don't work ? why script don't get "DEV_PLATFORM" value?

```
web_set_max_html_param_len("1000000");

web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=newParam", 
        "LB/IC=     <title>", 
        "RB/IC=</title>\r\n", 
        "Ordinal=all",  
        SEARCH_FILTERS, 
            "Scope=body",
        LAST);


web_add_cookie("com.mansuo.base.product.ProductCode=Portal; DOMAIN=192.168.1.86");

web_url("rdms", 
    "URL=http://192.168.1.86:8080/rdms", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t108.inf", 
    "Mode=HTTP", 
    LAST);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your left and right border is `<title> </title>` which indicates that you want the text between the title-tags, which is in the `<HEAD>` part of the HTML document. Meanwhile, you define the search filter `Scope=Body`. Basically, it seems you are searching within `<BODY>` for something that is located in `<HEAD>`. Try removing the `Scope=Body` or defining it as `Scope=All`.

Comment: Correction here to the _Scope_ parameter. It does not refer to the HTML elements, but to the HTTP Headers or HTTP Body. **From the Manual:**
Scope: Where to search for the delimited data. Optional.
The possible values are: "All"- Search the entire buffer, "Headers" - Search only the headers, "Body" - Search only body data, "Cookies" - Search only in cookies

Answer (score 2):

Change your boundary value:
Try:

```
web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=newParam", 
        "LB/IC=<title>", 
        "RB/IC=</title>", 
        "Ordinal=all",  
        SEARCH_FILTERS, 
        "Scope=body",
        LAST);
```

If it still does not work try Loadrunner design studio in LR 12 for Auto correlation.

Answer (score 1):

Also, `Ordinal=All` implies you want every occurrance of the parameter found. If you want the first occurance, use "Ordinal=1",

Answer (score 0):

Can you please let us know the detailed response which contain the value which you are trying to capture thru web reg save param ex?